# Is delete in Kubernetes idempotent

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is calling Delete in the Kubernetes go API an idempotent operation, i.e. can it safely be called twice?
If so, is there any documentation defining this property?
The go code just states

> Delete deletes the given obj from Kubernetes cluster.

Essentially, this statement is what one would expect anyway when looking at the code.

Comment: I think this question boils down to, "does HTTP DELETE in the Kubernetes REST API return 404 if the identified object doesn't exist?"  I can't find a clear answer to this in the [Kubernetes API overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/).  If you're worried about larger-scale raciness, there's also a possibility that something else is trying to create the object at the same time, so a second "delete" could delete a newly-created object.

Comment: Easy enough to test, right?  Just try to delete a non-existent object.

Comment: I'd prefer an answer that is not in the style of "I tried and it works".

Comment: It's not idempotent at least using kubectl client. This would error out. Perhaps, it's a good idea to check for the objects presence before deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api service is based on http, so you can check [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) about that

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the effect for a single such request.  Of the request methods defined by this specification, PUT, DELETE, and safe request methods are idempotent.

If your're using `kubectl` the delete command will fail on the second run, because the resource can not be found. You can prevent it from failing by using the `--ignore-not-found` flag.

```bash
$ kubectl run nginx --image nginx
pod/nginx created
$ kubectl delete pod nginx
pod "nginx" deleted 
$ kubectl delete pod nginx
Error from server (NotFound): pods "nginx" not found
$ kubectl delete pod nginx --ignore-not-found
```

So it's idempotent on the server but not on the client.